# Ubuntu server can SSH but cannot access internet

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet, dns

I try this command and this is what I get.

```
admin@grader:~$ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens32
iface ens32 inet static
        address 10.100.101.102
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.100.101.0
        broadcast 10.100.101.255
        gateway 10.100.101.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 10.100.101.1
        dns-search triamudom.ac.th
```

This is my `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.100.101.1
search triamudom.ac.th
```

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Could you [edit] your question and demonstrate how SSH works? Doesn’t it only work locally, for example? Ping does not work behind a proxy or if blocked by a firewall, you should also try `wget` or `curl`. Also `traceroute` may provide useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ping 8.8.8.8

If you get a successful reply then your DNS is not working.
Post here and we'll see from there.

Update1: 
Since you can ping 8.8.8.8 seems your dns is not resolving correctly.
A solution would be to just reconf your interface to use 8.8.8.8 as dns instead of that internal IP (10.100.101.1) you got there. Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Here is what i get `PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=22.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=22.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 time=22.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=119 time=22.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=119 time=22.6 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.571/22.615/22.691/0.194 ms`

Comment: Please upvote the answer and mark it as accepted. ty

Comment: Just for your info: 8.8.8.8 is google public IP for DNS. with this IP you won't be able to resolve local 10.x.x.x IPs. If you need that then you need to set back the DNS IP you had and move to your DNS machine and troubleshoot it.